# How to send form data and load the resulting page into and iframe

Tags: forms, iframe

Okay so I have a basic webpage that just load a simple form.

This form submits a text field, a radio button selection. Very simple.

It sends it to a webpage that uses the data and displays a webpage based on the data.

What I am wondering is how can I submit this data to the webpage, which is located on a different server, and display what that webpage would then display inside of an Iframe.

The reason I ask is I just wish to have an iframe that has almost like a header that stays anchored at the top of their resulting webpage with an advertisement.

Hopefully this is clear enough. I just can't seem to find what I am looking for :(

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this? The form will targeted to the iframe with the domain `http://example.com` and also take its post value

```
<form action="#" method="post" target="iframe_name">
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
 </form>

    <iframe src="http://example.com" name="iframe_name"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is headed in the direction I am going. When I add this very function to my page it simply creates the iframe on the same page. Would it be possible to make it load a separate page that is nothing but the ad and then the results displaying in the iframe? Thank you for your help :)